# Максимальный размер иконки для сайта (favicon)

Tags: веб-программирование, браузер, icon

Подскажите пожалуйста, какого размера (максимум) нужно делать иконку для сайта.
 То есть, в каком размере (сколько на сколько пикселей) её отображают браузеры?

Answer (score 2):

Вот [тут](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon) очень детально всё описано. Прочитайте статью полностью, она небольшая.

Comment: да и [тут](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon) даже все важное описано

Comment: @eicto, позвольте не согласиться? Очень базовые вещи описаны в русскоязычной статье, даже про Apple ничего не сказано, а между тем - это огромная доля посещаемости для сегодняшнего времени. И лучше сразу сделать favicon во всех размерах, чем потом искать, переделывать и дорабатывать.

Comment: Так там специконка а не favicon, я бы это поддерживать не стал из принципа. (учитывая что они игнорят стандарт как написано в конце статьи)